# php check array for certain value inside

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a function that is able to check an array for a certain value and if that value exists then to return the value of the index.

I have the following code that queries the db and puts the result in an array but when i pass that array into the function nothing is returned for some reason.

Can someone please help me with this.

```
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); 
    $conn = mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

    $sql="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(due_date,'%d') AS day,short,tid FROM tasks WHERE due_date BETWEEN '2014-8-01' AND '2014-8-31'";    

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        $events[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

    var_dump($events);
    echo "Check Array results is " . checkArray("15", $events);

    function checkArray($day, &$arr){
        $key = array_search($day, $arr);
        echo "the key is ". $key;
        return $key;
    }
```

This is the output of var_dump($events)

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["day"]=> string(2) "15"
        ["short"]=> string(6) "test 1"
        ["tid"]=> string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["day"]=> string(2) "31"
        ["short"]=> string(6) "test 2"
        ["tid"]=> string(1) "2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you just not checking for the day in the MySQL statement, why this extra step?

Comment: You have an array of arrays. You would need to loop through them to get the key with the corresponding value.

Comment: Can't you just add `WHERE day = [yourValue]` directly in your SQL request ?

Comment: I need to get all data in between those dates, its for a calendar app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for your `function checkArray()` and it will return the first matching key or false if the day is not found,

```
function checkArray($day, $array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (array_search($day, $value)) 
            return $key;  
     }
     return false; 
};
```

---

However, why don't you just add `day = '15'` in your SQL?

Comment: that worked perfect thanks, i don't do that in my sql, because i need to all the dates within that month, i just used 15 for testing, i actually have a loop that goes through all the days

Answer (score 0):

You want a recursive search of the array, if your array is more than one dimension.

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["day"]=> string(2) "15" 
        ["short"]=> string(6) "test 1" 
        ["tid"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["day"]=> string(2) "31" 
        ["short"]=> string(6) "test 2" 
        ["tid"]=> string(1) "2" 
    } 
}


<?php
    function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
        foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
            $current_key=$key;
            if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && 
                recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {

                return $current_key;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
 ?>
```

I took this from [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).